# How to find unknown IP address on Android

Tags: networking

I believe I have a sort of unique question in how would I determine an unknown IP address through an Android device which is connected directly to a IP enabled piece of hardware via USB-C to Ethernet adapter.

I understand that on the computers you can use the likes of ARP scans for such things, but is it possible to something similar on an android device?

The network address would be unknown and same with subnet.

Are they any known tools out there to do something over BOOTP, DCHP, Ethernet/IP devices

Comment: If I knew the IP range (i.e. subnet), a ping sweep would be my first tool. [There's an app for it.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordpress.mustalgo.pingsweep)

Comment: Almost everything that works on a Linux PC also works on Android devices. Privileged tasks may require a rooted device though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB wireless :- problem with IP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236511/adb-wireless-problem-with-ip)